# Tracking 3-day streaks when a condition is met in a column of a dataframe without double-counting streaks

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe made of climate observations for 8 different US cities.

I'm trying to find the number of heat waves (3 consecutive days with the max at or above 90 degrees) per every year for every location in the dataset.

I'm defining a heat wave as 3 consecutive days but 3 unique consecutive days.  For example:

```
If Aug. 8 hit 87
   Aug. 9 hit 90
   Aug. 10 hit 92
   Aug. 11 hit 94
   Aug. 12 hit 93
   Aug. 13 hit 101
   Aug. 14 hit 94
   Aug. 15 hit 77
```

In the 'HeatWave' column, there would be values on Aug. 9 and Aug. 12 of '1', reflecting 2 separate 3 day periods where the Max reached 90 or above.

My current strategy has not been working with such streaks of days.

I've been trying to use np.where.  First I check to see if the temp reached 90 or above on the day in question.  Next, I check ahead to see if the max reached at or above 90 on the two following days.  Finally, I check the two days prior to see if the HeatWave column does not have a '1' in it.  If all these conditions are met, a 1 is placed in the 'HeatWave' column for the row.

```
summer['Next90'] = summer.Max.shift(-1)
summer['Following90'] = summer.Max.shift(-2)
summer['HeatWave'] = 0    
summer['HeatWave'] = np.where((summer['Next90']>=90) & 
(summer['Max']>=90) & (summer['Following90']>=90) & (summer.shift(1) 
['HeatWave']!=1) & (summer.shift(2)['HeatWave']!=1), 1, np.nan)
```

The problem with this sequence is I don't think np.where can check the 'HeatWave' column after it just placed a 1 (or an np.nan) in the preceding row.  So, I get lots of '1's' in the HeatWave column, but the sequences end up being double-counted.  I also tried this in a for loop using iterrows, but landed at the same struggle.  Could anyone suggest a better way to go about this?

Comment: What is your expected out from this data?

Comment: So essentially, my dataframe would have a '1' in the HeatWave column at the BEGINNING of a 3-day stretch of days with Max >= 90.  There would not be another '1' in the HeatWave column until at least 2 days pass, regardless if those next 2 days also have a Max >=90 (prevent the double counting of the streak of 3 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can try (the sample data is shown at the end of the post)

1. get the data and then setup the streak number of days = 3

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file', sep='\s\s+', engine='python', parse_dates=['date'])
   # N-day streak
   N = 3
   ```
2. drop potential dupes, fix missing dates and set NULL 'temp' to 0

   ```
   # if there are duplicates in the same date, drop them and keep the one with highest temp
   df = df.sort_values(['date', 'temp'], ascending=[1,0]).drop_duplicates(subset=['date'])

   # fix missing dates issue and fill missing 'temp' with 0
   df = df.set_index('date').asfreq('D').reset_index().fillna(0)
   print(df)
   #         date  temp
   #0  2018-08-01    83
   #1  2018-08-02    99
   #2  2018-08-03    99
   #3  2018-08-04    87
   #4  2018-08-05    90
   #5  2018-08-06    92
   #6  2018-08-07     0
   #7  2018-08-08    92
   #8  2018-08-09    90
   #9  2018-08-10    92
   #10 2018-08-11    94
   #11 2018-08-12    93
   #12 2018-08-13   101
   #13 2018-08-14    94
   #14 2018-08-15    77
   ```
3. set up conditions which qualify for a heat wave

   ```
   # contition-1  df.temp >= 90
   c1 = df.temp.ge(90)
   ```
4. group consecutive rows based on condition-1 and label them with g

   ```
   # group label (each group forms a streak)
   g = (c1 != c1.shift()).cumsum()
   ```
5. define a new df1. For each group of g, find the following:

   - cnt: total number of row
   - n: cumcount() as sequence number
   - g: added here just for reference, not used for any futher calculations

     ```
     df1 = df.assign(
         cnt=df.groupby(g).date.transform('count')
       , n=df.groupby(g).agg('cumcount')
       , g=g
     )
     print(df1)
     #         date  temp  cnt  g  n
     #0  2018-08-01    83    1  1  0
     #1  2018-08-02    99    2  2  0
     #2  2018-08-03    99    2  2  1
     #3  2018-08-04    87    1  3  0
     #4  2018-08-05    90    2  4  0
     #5  2018-08-06    92    2  4  1
     #6  2018-08-07     0    1  5  0
     #7  2018-08-08    92    7  6  0
     #8  2018-08-09    90    7  6  1
     #9  2018-08-10    92    7  6  2
     #10 2018-08-11    94    7  6  3
     #11 2018-08-12    93    7  6  4
     #12 2018-08-13   101    7  6  5
     #13 2018-08-14    94    7  6  6
     #14 2018-08-15    77    1  7  0
     ```
6. define two more conditions:

   ```
   # condition-2: cnt >= N , a streak must have at least N rows
   c2 = df1.cnt.ge(N)

   # condition-3: (n%N)==0 and (n+N) <= cnt
   # the last n%N==0 might not have enough dates for a N-day streak
   c3 = df1.n.mod(N).eq(0) & df1.n.le(df1.cnt-N)
   ```
7. the final flag in df should have:

   ```
   df['flag'] = np.where(c1 & c2 & c3, 1, 0)
   print(df)
   #         date  temp  flag
   #0  2018-08-01    83     0
   #1  2018-08-02    99     0
   #2  2018-08-03    99     0
   #3  2018-08-04    87     0
   #4  2018-08-05    90     0
   #5  2018-08-06    92     0
   #6  2018-08-07     0     0
   #7  2018-08-08    92     1
   #8  2018-08-09    90     0
   #9  2018-08-10    92     0
   #10 2018-08-11    94     1
   #11 2018-08-12    93     0
   #12 2018-08-13   101     0
   #13 2018-08-14    94     0
   #14 2018-08-15    77     0
   ```
8. delete the temporary df1:

   ```
   del(df1)
   ```

**Sample data**

```
date           temp
Aug 1, 2018    83
Aug 2, 2018    99
Aug 2, 2018    65
Aug 3, 2018    99
Aug 2, 2018    70
Aug 4, 2018    87
Aug 5, 2018    90
Aug 6, 2018    92
Aug 8, 2018    92
Aug 9, 2018    90
Aug 10, 2018    92
Aug 11, 2018    94
Aug 12, 2018    93
Aug 13, 2018    101
Aug 14, 2018    94
Aug 15, 2018    77
```

Comment: This is absolutely awesome (I say this without having tested this yet, but I will do so tonight).  I can't thank you enough for taking the time to send this!

Comment: Works brilliantly!  I can't even begin to say how much I thank you.  Here is a small snippet of the code in action:  `climate[(climate['City']=='DFW') & (climate['Year']==2015) & (climate['Max']>=90)]
Out[13]: 
              Max   Min   Avg  ...   month_year  SnowObserved  flag
Date                           ...                                 
2015-05-18   91.0  68.0  79.5  ...      2015-05           NaN     0
2015-06-03   91.0  72.0  81.5  ...      2015-06           NaN     1
`

Comment: @wnjl, I am glad it worked for you. would you mind to upvote my answer if it helps. Enjoy a nice weekend :-)

Comment: I tried, but it won't count my upvote yet :-(  I guess I am too new.